# How can I find all the connected cities on graph with Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Program should check if there is a direct route between two given cities. Alternatively, it can list all the connected cities for a given city.

My Solution is:

I keep a list of cities I visit. If the next city is not the city I came from and the name of the next city is not on the list, I let you press the screen.

My code is:

```
% knowledge base

path(newyork,losangeles). 
path(losangeles,newyork). 

path(losangeles,chicago). 
path(chicago,losangeles). 

path(chicago,houston). 
path(houston,chicago). 

path(houston,newyork). 
path(newyork,houston). 

% rules
route(X,Y):-myroute(X,X,Y,[]).

myroute(X,Y,Z,_L):- path(Y,Z), not(X = Z).
myroute(X,Y,A,L):- path(Y,A), not(X = A) , not(member(A,L)),   
                   append(X,L,T) , myroute(Y,A,_Q,T).
```

Output:

> ```
> ?- route(newyork,Y). 
> Y = losangeles ;
> Y = houston ;
> false
> ```

Expected Output:

> ```
> ?- route(newyork,Y). 
> Y = losangeles ;
> Y = chicago ;
> Y = houston ;
> false
> ```

My code is check if there is a direct route between two given cities. It can't list all the connected cities for a given city. Where am I making mistakes?

Comment: Someone might provide a proper answer, but yes, your logic is false. I recommend you run a graphical tracer to see step by step what's happening and it will be obvious. If you're running standard swi-prolog, running `guitracer.` and then `trace.` and then your query, will bring up a nice debugging interface where you can follow your code step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's follow the logic of your code:

```prolog
?- route(newyork, Y).
```

Prolog tries to unify this with what it knows from the database. It finds this definition:
`route(X,Y):-myroute(X,X,Y,[]).`

Therefore it unifies `X` with `newyork` and proceeds to check if
`myroute(newyork, newyork, Y, [])` is true, as per the definition of `route`.

Prolog finds a match for that term in it database, with the first definition of the `myroute` predicate, and proceeds to unify `X`, `Y` and `_L` in that definition as `newyork`, `newyork` and `[]`, i.e. it checks to see if `myroute(newyork, newyork, Y, [])` can be satisfied given the definition for `myroute`.

According to the first definition of `myroute`, prolog checks to see if it can find a fact in its database that will satisfy `path(newyork, Z)`, such that Z is not newyork. There are two facts that can satisfy this, for `Z=losangeles` and for `Z=houston`. Note that there is no `path(newyork, chicago)` fact in the database, therefore this does not qualify as an answer given your current definitions.

Note also that if the first `myroute` definition fails, then so will the second one, since it checks for exactly the same things first! Therefore there will be no other solutions found via backtracking in this instance.

**What you should be doing instead**
I won't solve your exercise for you (especially since you didn't ask me to :p ) but in general, your myroute predicate is probably expected to work as follows:

```prolog
myroute(StartPoint, EndPoint, RouteSoFar) :- % your definition here
```

and called from `route` like so:

```prolog
route(X, Y) :- myroute(X, Y, []).
```

`RouteSoFar` is an accumulator; in the first call we call it with `[]` because we haven't visited any nodes, but in subsequent calls to myroute, it will be a list that you add to before calling the predicate again recursively. Somewhere in your predicate definition you'll have to check that the node you're about to visit isn't in the list of visited nodes already.

The logic of myroute is this: "There exists a myroute from X to Z if there is a simple path from X to Z (base case), OR if there is a path from X to an intermediate UNVISITED node Y, and then a myroute from that Y to Z (recursive case)".

Comment: also, to clarify, variable names are NOT shared between definitions. A `Y` in one definition has nothing to do with a `Y` in another, they are simply variable names internal to the scope of that definition.